# How to display TQDM from terminal into GUI progress bar?

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

Hello I am new to python and I am setting up a progress bar for a college project. Currently I have the progress bar running on background in the terminal with tqdm while the loop is running and returns the results in the main GUI body after loop is complete. I am trying to display the progress from the terminal into the main GUI body as progress bar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is part of the code:

````
    keywordlist = open('IP.txt', 'r')
    loglines = [n for n in logfile]
    keywords = [n for n in keywordlist]
    for line in tqdm.tqdm(loglines):
        progress.update()
        progress['value'] = 100
        time.sleep(0.01)
        for word in keywords:
            if word.strip() in line.strip():
                processes.append(line)
                with open("DNSResults.txt", "w") as txt_file:
                    for line in processes:
                        txt_file.write("".join(line)+"\n")
    logfile = open('DNSResults.txt', 'r')
    keywordlist = open('EmotetIP.txt', 'r')
    loglines = [n for n in logfile]
    keywords = [n for n in keywordlist]
    
    for line in loglines:
        for word in keywords:
            if word.strip() in line.strip():    
                msg3 ="Matches found with the following Ip Adresses: " + str(word) +"\n"
                txt.insert(0.0,msg3)```
````

And than I have tkinter progress bar used for the GUI.

```
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'determinate')
progress.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tqdm.gui.

```
from tqdm.gui import trange, tqdm
for i in trange(<some amount or something>):
     pass
```

```
from tqdm.gui import tqdm_gui
for i in tqdm_gui(range(<some amount or something>)):
     pass
```